# Why do I get "network control block (ncb) is in use on a remote adapter" with DHCP requests?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, dhcp

Clients on our network recently started receiving this error when attemping to acquire an IP Address from our DHCP Server:

"the name specified in the network control block (ncb) is in use on a remote adapter"

The DHCP Server is a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, most of the client are Win 7.

Can't find much on that error, anyone have an idea what could cause it?

Comment: This issue happen to us after migrating from 2k3 to a 2k8 DHCP server due to a stale dns ptr record with the old DHCP server. Make sure your DNS is clean after a migration!

Comment: This might also be the result if you setup Windows NLB in a network and doesn't configure it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check

- Do you have conflict resolution turned on for the DHCP server?
- Is the DHCP server registered in AD

Answer (score 1):

Try reconciling DHCP server (right click scope node, and click "Reconcile"). Finish wizard, and try renewing IP on the computer having the issue.